# Directive not working

Tags: angularjs-directive

I am fiddling with the angular directives but I don't know why this simple example is not working:

http://plnkr.co/edit/vmhqa0HUv60fF7K3bJWC?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first character of directive name needs lowercase :) ("customInput")

Comment: I have update the plnkr! but when I see the o/p in the dev tools window. I see this.`<input required="" type="" name="">`. Any idea?

Comment: Just use '<input required />' as template or use a different name for attributes.

Comment: But I am replacing the original element and in that case I need to know its attributes!

Comment: When you specify replace: true, the entire element is replaced by the template but the attributes of the original element are appended to the template element. You should consider using custom attribute names (es. <custom-input ctype="text" cname="uname"/>)